# does disparity maps give depth in meter if focal length and disparity are in pixel?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, disparity-mapping

I am trying to find depth using a stereo camera. I created a depth map or disparity matrix which are from 0 to 255 (pixel value). Now after creating a depth map, I want to find real depth using formula,

```
depth = (baseline*focallength)/disparity-value
Here,
the baseline in (meter)
focal length in (pixel)
disparity-value in (pixel)
```

So I want to ask if I calculate depth, will that depth in pixel or in a meter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you substitute your units you get: `depth = baseline (meter) * focal length (pixel) / disparity-value (pixel)`. So the result is in **meters** because pixels are canceled down.

Comment: Piotr Siekański Thank-you. I want to ask another question. Is disparity matrix value which is from 0 to 255 (0 for black and 255 for white) are pixel values? I just want to confirm.